# correct datatype for storing negative numbers

Tags: mysql

I have to save the the value `-1`. Is for it more correct to use a data type of `tinyint(1)` or `tinyint(2)` and why?

I know that I can also store with tinyint tinyint (1) many more digits, but I want to know what you use in my case.

Comment: Do you also want to store other values? Or just `0` / `-1`?

Comment: I want to store other values...

Answer (score 2):

You may use [DECIMAL](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/fixed-point-types.html) which would be probably the best datatype for storing negative numbers.

> Standard SQL requires that DECIMAL(5,2) be able to store any value
>   with five digits and two decimals, so values that can be stored in the
>   salary column range from -999.99 to 999.99

Although in your case you may use [TINYINT(1)](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/integer-types.html) as  it takes 1 byte of storage and its range is -128 to 127.

On a side note:

You may also like to know what is the [difference between TinyInt(1) and TinyInt(2)](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/numeric-type-overview.html)

> M indicates the maximum display width for integer types. The maximum
>   display width is 255. **Display width is unrelated to the range of
>   values a type can contain, as described in Section 11.2, “Numeric
>   Types”.** For floating-point and fixed-point types, M is the total
>   number of digits that can be stored.